# Stripe API - Workaround for case sensitive email

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

I'm using the Stripe API and this is using the customer email address in the database however we've just had an issue where someone is signing in to the page using a different case to their sign up and it is not showing them as subscribed.

Obviously I'd like to convert the Stripe emails to all be lowercase but I'm not sure how to do this after getting the email. I am converting the user input to be all lowercase but that just means that if the email in Stripe is not lowercase they are not showing as subscribed.

Thanks in advance

```
$(document).ready(function() {

                var productIDFull = "prod_key00000";
                var email = '@User.Identity.Name';
                
                var emailLower = email.toLowerCase();

                // check if user has made a purchase in stripe for this product
                var hasPurchasedFull = false;
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: 'https://api.stripe.com/v1/customers?email=' + emailLower,
                    headers: {
                        'authorization': 'Bearer sk_live_0000'
                    },
                    success: function(data) {
                        var isSubscribed = false;

                        // loop through each customer returned
                        $.each(data.data,
                            function(i, customer) {

                                console.log(customer);
                                var subscriptions = customer.subscriptions;
                                console.log(subscriptions);
                                // loop through each sub
                                $.each(subscriptions.data,
                                    function(j, subscription) {
                                        console.log(subscription);

                                        var subData = subscription.items.data;
                                        // loop through each plan
                                        $.each(subData,
                                            function(k, planData) {
                                                console.log(planData);

                                                if (planData.plan.product == 'prod_Kc3e_0000' && planData.plan.usage_type == 'licensed') {
                                                    isSubscribed = true;
                                                }
                                            });

                                    });
```

Answer (score 0):

> I am converting the user input to be all lowercase but that just means
> that if the email in Stripe is not lowercase they are not showing as
> subscribed.

This sounds expected based on Stripe's documentation: https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/list?lang=curl#list_customers-email

The `email` value is case sensitive, so customer `Test@example.com` will not be returned if you list customers with email `test@example.com`

I think a better way to handle this is to store a mapping of Stripe customer IDs and email addresses in an internal database and compare against this database instead of a customer list call.

Comment: Thank you I did consider this, I think you're right.

Answer (score 0):

If you're enforcing case sanitization in the future, rather than save a mapping, you could also retroactively go back and clean your old customer data.

[Here's a tool I wrote to do so via Stripe's API](https://github.com/anjayc/normalize-stripe-emails). Don't forget that you'll also need to do the same to wherever else you have that data (e.g. postgres). Perform at your own risk!